# Laravel Eloquent: Cache an eager loading Model without a specific relation

Tags: laravel, caching, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm already saving a Model to the cache, because it's changing only once a day:

```
cache()->remember($key , $time , function() use ($id) {
        return $profile = Profile::with('images.type')->find($id);
```

That work's perfect till now. But now I want to add a relation to that Model, which is User specific.

```
cache()->remember($key , $time , function() use ($id) {
        return $profile = Profile::with(['images.type',
                                         'messages.type' => function ($query) {
                                            $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
                                         }])->find($id);
```

I'm totally aware that I would save User specific content to the cache for everbody now, which sucks :-)

So. Is it possible to run this query as one Model like it is shown above, but without saving the relation 'messages.type' to the cache? I hope you have an idea!

Comment: If you are not saving the `messages.type` you will have to look for it on the DB. If you are caching a user (why ? this is really strange) does it mean that this or each `User` model is being required let's say once per day ? If that is true, why would you cache a model instead of serving it right away ? if that is false, why would you not cache it ? What I am trying to ask is why are you caching a model so important as a Profile ? Could you explain more ? I think your solution is not caching this information at all (Profile), so maybe the problem is somewhere else and we can help you fix it

Comment: `Profile` is not the same as `User`. I don't want to cache the `User`, but caching the `Profile(s)` makes sense because it's a lot of them and with a huge stack of information in it (the example above is simplified) and they change only once a day.

Comment: Still strange to cache a model, why are you doing so ? does it get lots of hits to deserve to cache it ?

Comment: I expect the app to have many ten thousands of profiles with even more thousands of views every day. So why is caching not a good idea in your eyes?

Comment: I have never seen someone cache this type of data in my 7 years of experience, that is why there is like an alarm going on in my mind. What is the problem of not caching this and let it be get every time ? if you cache the second query, your problem could be that the user id could change ?

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-caching ??

Comment: That would be a good implementation, but still, if you are going to cache a lot of things, you have to be really careful, it is bad to hit the DB with 1 million comments per second, but it is also bad to cache 10 million or more comments on cache because you are afraid of getting hit 1 time to get those comments per second, you have to find a balance, one thing is to store a count and other is to store a whole model(s). Follow that tutorial, it is a good approach.